# I want to replace a string between delimiters by looking up in properties file using ansible

Tags: python, ansible, devops

I want to replace a string in between two @ characters

Something like this

Hi I am  @Something.great@ from a planet @planet.outside.earth@

from a properties file 
where values are

Something.great = Niel Armstrong
planet.outside.earth = Mars

So this should convert the above text to

Hi I am  Niel Armstrong from a planet Mars

I have to achieve this using Ansible

Using lookup and replace

EDIT 1:

No For the two answers below.
I don't have any idea what keys I have in between N number of files.
I have to search a regex in folder having 100 files may contain 1000 keys in between @myKey@ .

So I have to First search what is the value in file in this case myKey which has to come from some regex search and then lookup that search value in a lookup properties file where the value of myKey is present.

My properties file looks like this.

```
myKey=Ankit
YourKey=Kevin
OtherKey=Vladimir
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html#replace-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression) module, if the string is in a file

```
- replace:
    path: "{{ path_to_template }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
  loop:
    - regexp: '@Something.great@'
      replace: 'Niel Armstrong'
    - regexp: '@planet.outside.earth@'
      replace: 'Mars'
```

, or use [regex_replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) filter if the string is available in a variable

```
- set_fact:
    string: "{{ string | regex_replace( item.regexp, item.replace) }}"
  loop:
    - regexp: '@Something.great@'
      replace: 'Niel Armstrong'
    - regexp: '@planet.outside.earth@'
      replace: 'Mars'
```

---

If you replace the markers '@@' with '{{ }}' the variables will be substituted. For example

```
  vars:
    string: "Hi I am {{ Something.great }} from a planet {{ planet.outside.earth }}"
    Something:
      great: "Niel Armstrong"
    planet:
      outside:
        earth: "Mars"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: string
```

, or with the template

```
$ cat test.j2 
Hi I am {{ Something.great }} from a planet {{ planet.outside.earth }}
```

and the task below

```
- template:
    src: test.j2
    dest: "{{ path_to_file_with_the_substituted_text }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
---
- hosts: local_test # local_test
  vars:
    string: "Hi I am @Something.great@ from a planet @planet.outside.earth@"
    something:
      great: "Niel Armstrong"
    planet:
      outside:
        earth: "Mars"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ string | replace('@Something.great@', something.great) | replace ('@planet.outside.earth@', planet.outside.earth) }}"
```

Output:

```
 TASK [debug] 
 "msg": "Hi I am Niel Armstrong from a planet Mars"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

First I will search the directory for the specific regex and store it in Register.

1. ```
     - name: Search Tokens
           find:
             paths: "{{ HOME_DIR }}"
             hidden: yes
             contains: "^.*(@.*@).*$"
             recurse: no
             use_regex: yes
             file_type: file
             patterns: "^(?!.*pattern\\.sh).*$"
           register: filesname
   ```
2. I will write the list of files in a separate text file config.txt

```
  - name: Write list of files to be read for tokens
      lineinfile: 
        path: /config.txt 
        line: "{{item.file.path}}"
        create: yes 
        state: present
      with_items: 
        - "{{filesname}}"
```

3. Now I will Loop Through the config file for every file inside read-replaceyaml

```
 - name: Loop through the tasks
      include_tasks: read-replace.yaml
      with_items: "{{ lookup('file', '/config.txt').splitlines() }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: file
```

4. In read-replace.yml

I will read file content and replace the token at the same time

```
 - debug:
        msg="{{lookup('file', '{{file}}')}}"
      register: fileContent

    - name: Storing the content of the file
      set_fact:
        fileString: "{{fileContent.msg}}"

 - name: Find the tokens (@----@) in the fileString
      set_fact:
        tokens: "{{ fileString | regex_findall(regexp)}}"
      vars:
        regexp: '\@.*?\@'

    - name: Print Token Objects
      debug:
        var: tokens

    - debug:
        msg="{{ lookup('ini', '{{item}} type=properties file=/lookup.properties') }}"
      with_items:
       - "{{tokens}}"
      register: myresult

    - debug:
        var : myresult


   - name: Replace the token in the configuration files
      replace:
        path: {{file}}
        regexp: '{{token}}' 
        replace: "{{ lookup('ini', '{{token}} type=properties file=/lookup.properties')}}"
      with_items: "{{tokens}}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: token
```